# PDFBox2.0.26 use TTC Fonts

Tags: java, fonts, pdfbox

I am trying to use pdfbox to add text watermark to pdf, but I encountered a problem when adding ttc format fonts.

```
    Font2D font2D = FontUtilities.getFont2D(font);
    String fontEnName = font2D.getFamilyName(Locale.ENGLISH);

    PDFont pdfFont = PDType0Font.load(doc, new TrueTypeCollection(fontFile).getFontByName(fontEnName), true);

    PDPageContentStream contents = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page, PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.APPEND, true, true);
    contents.beginText();
    contents.setFont(pdfFont, fontHeight);
```

First of all, *Font2D* and *FontUtilities* are internal classes, which may be deleted in the future, which is not a good solution. Second, the obtained *fontEnName* is not necessarily the parameter required by *getFontByName*, maybe *fontEnName* is
**simsum**, but the parameter of *getFontByName* needs **SimSun**, and the two names are not matching,there are other ttc Font related example, is there any other good solution?

Comment: What exactly is your question? How to get the correct names of all the fonts in a ttc file? (There can be several)

Comment: The main problem is to get the font name that can be recognized by **getFontByName**

Comment: The issue has been resolved, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This shows the names:

```
    TrueTypeCollection ttc = new TrueTypeCollection(new File("c:/windows/fonts/batang.ttc"));
    ttc.processAllFonts(new TrueTypeCollection.TrueTypeFontProcessor()
    {
        @Override
        public void process(TrueTypeFont ttf) throws IOException
        {
            System.out.println(ttf.getName());
        }
    });
```

Comment: I found the above method, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

ttc Font:

```
Font font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, fb);
font = font.deriveFont(Font.PLAIN, fontHeight);
String fontEnName = font.getPSName();
PDFont pdfFont = PDType0Font.load(doc, new TrueTypeCollection(fontFile).getFontByName(fontEnName), true);
```